Trying to run R (programming language) in powershell results in repeating the last command
When trying to run an R terminal with command R (like it works in cmd and other terminals from other operating systems) I run into the problem that command r or R seems to be reserved as running the last passed command in PowerShell. Is there a way to reset that shortcut or to bypass it somehow so that I can run an R Terminal the usual way?
Any help is welcome. Below you can see the behavior shown by my system/PowerShell.
(base) PS C:\Users\reelsaemon> echo hello
hello
(base) PS C:\Users\reelsaemon> R
echo hello
hello
(base) PS C:\Users\reelsaemon>


In PowerShell, r is a built-in alias for the Invoke-History cmdlet, which explains the behavior you saw (as NTFS is (by default), PowerShell commands are case-insensitive too, so that invoking R is the same as invoking r).
Due to PowerShell's command precedence, an alias named r takes precedence over an external program such as r.exe. [1]
You have two options:

Ad hoc, simply include the filename extension in your call to R: r.exe

If you want the convenience of invoking R simply by r, you must delete the alias, which you can do with: Remove-Item alias:r

To make this deletion take effect in future PowerShell sessions too, add the command to your $PROFILE file.




[1] You can use Get-Command to find out what command (form) a given name in effect refers to: Get-Command r; to see all command forms associated with that name (all but the first one will be shadowed): Get-Command -All r

@ReelSaemon, if you decide to remove the PowerShell r alias, it only needs to be put into one (1) of the four (4) Powershell "profile" files.
